# Como evito la implementacion de un método en una clase que implementa una interfaz?

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente consulta, una interfaz llamada `ITipoDispositivo` y dos clases `DispositivoEstandar` y `DispositivoInteligente` que implementan la interfaz. Ambas clases tienen distintos métodos (ninguna que ver con la otra) Es posible limitar entre las clases que para que no puedan invocar métodos de la otra clase que no tienen implementación?
También tengo una clase Dispositivo que tiene una referencia a la interfaz y de acuerdo a una decisión se usa uno u otro Dispositivo. La idea es implementar un strategy.

```
public interface ITipoDispositivo {
  public void apagarse();
  public Integer consumo(Integer horasUtilizado);
}

public class DispositivoEstandar implements ITipoDispositivo{
 //no deberia implementar este metodo 
 public void apagarse();
 //este metodo si lo implementa
 public Integer consumo(Integer horasUtilizado);
}

public class DispositivoInteligente implements ITipoDispositivo{
 //este metodo si lo implementa    
 public void apagarse();
 //no deberia implementar este metodo 
 public Integer consumo(Integer horasUtilizado);

}

public class Dispositivo {

  private ITipoDispositivo dispositivo;

  public void administrarTipoDispositivoEstandar(){
    dispositivo = new DispositivoEstandar();
    this.setDispositivo(dispositivo);
  }

  public void administrarTipoDispositivoInteligente(){
    dispositivo = new DispositivoInteligente();
    this.setDispositivo(dispositivo);

   }
```

}

Saludos.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenid@ a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: No tiene sentido que implementes una interfaz si no vas a implementar todos sus métodos.

Comment: Lo otro es que si ésos métodos son propios de dispositivoInteligente entonces no deberían estar en la interfaz. La interfaz solo debe tener aquellos métodos que deben ser implementados por ambos dispositivos como podría ser llamar, enviar mensaje, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Has escuchado de las clases Adaptadoras. Tienes que crear una clase adaptadora para `ITipoDispositivo` una clase `TipoDispositivoAdapter`. Las clases adaptadoras implementan interfaces con muchos métodos pero para todos ellos proporcionan cuerpos vacíos por si no necesitas implementar todos ellos. Una vez creada la clase adaptadora es conveniente que siempre la uses, pues si se añaden nuevos métodos a la interfaz solo tendrás que añadir el método en la clase adaptadora y no en todo tu código que es como te ocurre. Ejemplo:

```
class TipoDispositivoAdapter extends ITipoDispositivo{ 
      ... 
}
```

Las clases adaptadoras se usan mucho para manejar eventos en `Swing`. Por ejemplo las siguientes interfaces tienen clases adaptadoras:

- `ComponentListener` posee `ComponentAdapter`
- `ContainerListener` posee `ContainerAdapter`
- `FocusListener` posee `FocusAdapter`
- `KeyListener` posee `KeyAdapter`
- `MouseListener` posee `MouseAdapter`
- `MouseMotionListener` posee `MouseMotionAdapter`
- `WindowListener` posee `WindowAdapter`

**Actualización:**

De acuerdo con tu edición y con la definición de [el patrón strategy](https://www.seas.es/blog/informatica/patrones-de-diseno-en-java-patron-strategy/) te falta la clase abstracta.

Answer (score 0):

Se supone que las interfaces unen las clases con métodos en común...
Puedes hacer esto ..

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean bool = (1 == Math.floor(Math.random()*2));
    Dispositivos dispositivos = bool ? new DispositivoEstandar():new DispositivoInteligente();

    switch(dispositivos.getType()){
        case estandar:
            //dispositivos.action(null);
            Apagable apg = (Apagable)dispositivos;
            break;
        case inteligente:
            //Integer inte = dispositivos.action(2);
            Consumible consu = (Consumible)dispositivos;
            break;
    }
}

public static interface Dispositivos {
    public TipoDispositivo getType();
    public Integer action(Integer inte);
}
public static interface Consumible{
    public Integer consumo(Integer inte);
}
public static interface Apagable{
    public void apagar();
}
public static enum TipoDispositivo{
    estandar,
    inteligente;
}
public static class DispositivoEstandar implements Dispositivos,Apagable{

    @Override
    public void apagar(){
        // TODO: Implement this method
    }
    @Override
    public TipoDispositivo getType(){
        return TipoDispositivo.estandar;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer action(Integer inte){
        apagar();
        return null;
    }
}
public static class DispositivoInteligente implements Dispositivos,Consumible{

    @Override
    public TipoDispositivo getType(){
        return TipoDispositivo.inteligente;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer action(Integer inte){
        return consumo(inte);
    }
    @Override
    public Integer consumo(Integer inte){
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return null;
    }
}
```